# AWS aurora に psql にて接続できるが、insertできない

Tags: aws, postgresql

Amazon Linux にpostgresqlクライアントのみインストールしてAuroraに接続して使いたいと考えています。Auroraはpostgresqlです。

```
psql -h host -d database -U username
```

で接続やselectもできます。ただしInsertしようとすると以下のエラーになります。

```
ERROR:  cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction
```

接続先DBは別途WindowsのGUIクライアントにて書き込みできることは確認しています。
psqlに何か設定が必要なのでしょうか？
やりたいことはバッチでpsqlにてファイルを読み込ませてデータをinsertすることです。

Answer (score 1):

「ERROR:  cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction」というメッセージが出たという事は、その前に
"SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY ・・・"というような、トランザクションを読み取り専用にする設定が為されているのでしょう。

Insertはデータの書き込み(追加)をするのですから、読み取りでないのは明らか。
それを読み取り専用に設定したトランザクションで実行するのは、無理があると思います。